# How to ParametricPlot an InterpolatingFunction

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

Hi  I can `Plot` the result of an `NDSolve` (toy example), but I cannot `ParametricPlot` it.

```
sol = NDSolve[{s'[t] == -s[t], i'[t] == -s[t], s[0] == 1, 
    i[0] == .1}, {s[t], i[t]}, {t, 0, 2}] ;

Plot[{  s[t] /. sol, i[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 2}]
ParametricPlot[{  s[t] /. sol, i[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, just adding `Evaluate` does it

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{  s[t], i[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 2}]
```

Still, I would like to understand why that is required with `ParametricPlot` but not with `Plot`

Comment: I believe you should execute the argument of `ParametricPlot` in each to see the difference. I think you’ll find that the code in the question does not have the form of xy coordinates. (In the docs, they sometimes use `First[sol]` instead of `sol` for this reason.)

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{s[t], i[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 2}]` or `ParametricPlot[{s[t] /. sol[[1]], i[t] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 2}]`